# the domain stackoverflow.com is for sale

Tags: support, stack-overflow, connectivity

I am getting this page whenever I am trying to open stackoverflow.com. Is anybody else getting  similar error page.

[image]

Comment: Works OK for me.

Comment: No repro. Most likely you're a victim of poisoned DNS or worse. Can you please post a traceroute to stackoverflow.com?

Comment: I am facing this problem only in my office system. may be some proxy settings or firewall causing this.

Comment: Same, no repro. As your location is put as "India" and one of the ad's is for Air India I'd say this is a more localised problem.

Comment: [BuyDomains.com does list stackoverflow.com as taken and unavailable!](http://www.buydomains.com/find-premium-domains/search-results.jsp?keywords=stackoverflow&p=.com&searchBtn.x=0&searchBtn.y=0) I'd drop BuyDomains a note and ask them what's going on (can't do, not at home).

Comment: That doesn't matter, we'd need a traceroute to determine anything. Also, your DNS-Server would be interesting.

Comment: More than likely, BuyDomains simply has a site configured at an IP address only, which says what ever domain name that you use to load it by is for sale. The principle being they only point domains they own that are for sale to that web server. Somewhere, (perhaps through problems noted above), Vivart's work connection's DNS is reporting the BuyDomain's "for sale" IP address for StackOverflow.com.

Comment: Quick, buy it! you could make a fortune on advertising!

Comment: sorry guys I can't reply in this thread from office because now meta is also redirecting to similar page.

Comment: @Vivart Your office is definitely suffering some form of poisoned DNS. You (or your IT people) need to examine your DNS configuration, check for viruses, and generally investigate.

Comment: thanks @DaveRandom. So DNS is giving wrong ip(ip of BuyDomain or ip that is configured on BuyDomain for sale) for SO and BuyDomain is using address showing on top banner. My understanding is right or am i missing something?

Comment: @Vivart Indeed that would seem to be the case - try an [`nslookup`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200525) at your office and you will find it give a different answer to the answers you get in places where it works.

Comment: That "embroidered ribbon over shiny black plastic" look is nicer than orange boxes on a white page, though.